# Change jQuery to ReactJS with with css class and toggleClass

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-hooks

hello I have trouble with changing my jQuery code into ReactJS

This is jQuery code that I want to change to ReactJS

```
   $(function () {
      if ($('#ms-menu-trigger')[0]) {
         $('body').on('click', '#ms-menu-trigger', function () {
            $('.ms-menu').toggleClass('toggled');
         });
      }
   });
```

HTML code:

```
          <div className='ms-body'>
           <div className='action-header clearfix'>
              <div className='visible-xs' id='ms-menu-trigger'>
                 <i className='fa fa-bars'></i>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Inside React I tried something like this

In HTMLL:

```
   const [mobileChat, setMobileChat] = useState(true);

   const handleToggle = () => {
     setMobileChat(!mobileChat);
   };
       
         <div
           className={`ms-body ${
              mobileChat ? 'ms-menu-trigger' : null}`}
        >
           <div className='action-header clearfix'>
              <div className='visible-xs' id='ms-menu-trigger'>
                 <i className='fa fa-bars'></i>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Maybe somebody can help me with this converts staff

Comment: code looks good. what's the trouble you're having?

Comment: CSS class not change when, maybe I write something wrong with this part "$('.ms-menu').toggleClass('toggled');"